i am unable to change brightnes in my laptop and the laptop i am using is Asus TUF F17

I tried to change the brightness through this setting

Have you tried the keyboard shortcut? It may be f7 or f8 for example - sometimes you have to hold down fn at the same time, sometimes you don’t.

This question is similar to: Ubuntu 20.04 brightness adjust not working. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
